# Rails3: How to implement multiple checkboxes in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I have now gives me a dropdown menu where I can only select one:

```
<%= form_for(@submission) do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :id, Submission::SUB_ID, :to_s, :to_s %>
<% end %>
```

where `SUB_ID=[1,2,3]` in model `Submission`

I want to implement a checkbox instead of a dropdown menu so that I can select multiple `SUB_ID` (i.e. 1&2 or 1&3 or 2&3 or 1&2&3). I tried to use this but it does not work:

```
<%= f.check_box :id, Submission::SUB_ID, :to_s, :to_s %>
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe multiple select will solution for you http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# view
<%= form_for(@submission) do |f| %>
  <%= Submission::SUB_ID.each do |sub_id| %>
    <%= f.checkbox 'ids[]', value: sub_id, checked: @submission.id == sub_id %>
    <%= sub_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# controller
params[:submission][:ids].each do |checked_sub_id|
  # do your logic here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this one is the closest, however, the sub_id style seems to be a little bit messy: all the ids are inline with a single checkbox

Comment: The style does not matter here: now that you know how to generate checkboxes for each sub_id, you can style it as your wishes. I just posted the least code possible to make it "universal"

Answer (score 1):

you have to iterate over SUB_ID
somehow like this...

```
<% Submission::SUB_ID.each do |ssid| %>
   <%= f.check_box "ids[]", value: ssid %>
<% end %>
```

or you can use `formtastic gem`. it has `:as=>:check_boxes` input fields http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/nuatt-formtastic-0.2.3/Formtastic/Inputs/CheckBoxesInput.html

Answer (score 0):

The core answer is you need to loop over each item in `Submission::SUB_ID` and make a checkbox for each id.  Depending on how your models are set up and what you want to do - you may need to be much more involved in the form building.  I hesitate to provide specific examples without know more about how you want the data to come back to the controller

```
<%= form_for(@submission) do |f| %>
    <% Submission::SUB_ID.each do sub_id %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag 'submission_ids[]', sub_id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that that will not default anything to checked and it does not come back as part of the submission parameters.

Usually when I have a similar situation I'm using nested forms to add or remove objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4, there is a new helper, `collection_check_boxes`, which helps streamline the building of your check boxes.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :submission_ids, Submission::SUB_ID, :to_s, :to_s %>
```

Documentation:

- [Form builder version](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) - which wraps...
- ...the [general form options helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

If you look at the documentation in the second link, you'll also find how to use the optional block syntax to customise the HTML structure for each check box.